# Toast ui (tui) datepicker how reset change date?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, tui

How to reset selected date in tui datepicker

```js
let calendarNum = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar').length;
  for(let i = 0; i < calendarNum; i++){
  let container = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar')[i];
  let dateInput = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker-input')[i];
  let instance = new tui.DatePicker(container, {
      language: 'en',
      input: {
        element: dateInput,
        format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
      },
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="group-input gi-date">             <div class="date-picker-wrap">              <div class="tui-datepicker-input tui-datetime-input tui-has-focus">                 <input type="text" name="date-before" class="date-input datepicker-input" aria-label="Date-Time">                             <span class="tui-ico-date"></span> </div>
    <div class="calendar" style="margin-top: -1px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/dvsnic/pen/YzpEyQj)

Comment: As per their documentation, you can set null. https://nhn.github.io/tui.date-picker/latest/DatePicker#setNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least 2 ways to do this:

- First, you can simply set the value of the datepicker to `null`:

  `document.querySelector("input.datepicker-input").value = null`
- Secondly, you can call the `setNull()` method on the `datepicker` object:

  `instance.setNull()`

Below is an example of both methods based on your code. **Note** that this snippet may give a script error on Stack Overflow due to tui attempting to access `localStorage` in a sandboxed environment. If that occurs, you can [view the snippet on JSFiddle instead](https://jsfiddle.net/6wghd02o/1/).

```js
let calendarNum = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar').length;

let container = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar')[0];
let dateInput = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker-input')[0];
let instance = new tui.DatePicker(container, {
  language: 'en',
  input: {
    element: dateInput,
    format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
  },
});


function setNull1() {
  document.querySelector("input.datepicker-input").value = null;
}

function setNull2() {
  instance.setNull();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.date-picker/latest/tui-date-picker.css" />
<script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.date-picker/latest/tui-date-picker.js"></script>
<div class="group-input gi-date">
  <div class="date-picker-wrap">
    <div class="tui-datepicker-input tui-datetime-input tui-has-focus"> <input type="text" name="date-before" class="date-input datepicker-input" aria-label="Date-Time"> <span class="tui-ico-date"></span> </div>
    <div class="calendar" style="margin-top: -1px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="setNull1();">
Reset By Setting Value to Null
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setNull2();">
Reset By Calling setNull()
</button>
```